# pgAdmin 4.19 “Error message” error fetching SQl for script: 'attname'

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin-4

I have a schema and role/user as same name, "cidrmgt".  I granted all privileges on database dbname to cidrmgmt and all tables in schema_name (cidrmgmt) to cidrmgmt.  I can logon as cidrmgmt and see a schema existed but cannot select tables, undate, delete, insert.  I get error with "Error fetching SQL for script:'attname'.   What is it and how can I resolve this error?  From the query_tool, I can run select and insert into the schema.table.  Even from postgres user, I cannot do select, insert, delete, update table as the owner
Also even when I grant as syntax

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER cidrmgmt 
IN SCHEMA cidrmgmt GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO cidrmgmt;
```

it complains "ERROR: must be member of role "cidrmgmt" SQL state:42501"
i am grant role to master_user

```
GRANT cidrmgmt to PSmasteruser ;
```

ERROR: role psmasteruser does not exist SQL state: 42704 
not even to postgres

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved when I upgraded pgAdmin 4.19 in AWS